# How to categorize month/day/year into a period of months in R

Tags: r

Sorry, I am very new to R. Most of my experience is in Matlab so I am hoping I can find a solution in R
I have data that looks like this:

```
Value Date
    1     1/10/2018
    2     1/14/2018
    3     1/21/2018
    4     2/22/2018
    .     . 
    .     .
    .     .
    16    4/21/2020
```

I want to categorize the days in Jan-2018 for example to be labeled "1', Feb-2018 would be labeled "2" etc. I am hoping my data would look like this:

```
Value Month
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: you can use `df %>% mutate(Month = lubridate::month(Date))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, extract the 'Month' with `format`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df2 <- df1 %>%
   transmute(Value, Month = format(mdy(Date), '%m'))
```